# how can i put drawable in onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, kotlin, onsaveinstancestate

I am using `onSaveInstanceState` to save a data item and I need to save a drawble as well, but there's no method called `putDrawable`. Therefore, how can I store a drawable in a `Bundle`?

This my code:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putParcelable("item", item)
    outState.putDrawable("drawable", drawable) // This line is not compiling
}

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    item = savedInstanceState?.getParcelable("item") ?: item
    return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to put a drawable in the bundle? Can't you reload the drawable from the resources again?

Comment: i do that in bottom sheet dialog i get drawble from fragment

Comment: I think the above comment is trying to say that, If the bottom sheet is getting the drawable from the fragment, why does the fragment cant pass a resource as in an `Int `R.drawable.bear`. Also, why is not compiling? What does the IDE says when you hover the mouse over the error? If the error is during the build what is the error message? Not compiling as in a crash? What does the error message says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is NO way you can pass a drawable in a [**`android.os.Bundle`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle).

What you can instead do is to create a class with a static object of drawable. You can store the drawable in it when `onSaveInstanceState()` triggers. And then use the same class to retrieve back the drawable. The code given below will explain better:

1. The additional class

   ```
   class VariablesHelper(){
      companion object{
         var drawable?: Drawable =  null
      }
   }
   ```
2. For setting the drwable

   ```
   override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
      VariablesHelper.drawable = drawable
   }
   ```
3. For getting the drawable, use

   ```
   val drawable?:Drawable = VariablesHelper.drawable
   ```